# Using 也 (ye3) vs. 又 (you4)?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

What's the difference between 也 (ye3) vs. 又 (you4)?

These two links, [link1](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/The_%22also%22_adverb_%22ye%22) and [link2](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22again%22_in_the_past_with_%22you%22), discuss them individually but do not contrast them.

This [last link](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Comparing_%22zai%22_and_%22you%22) contrasts 又 with 再 (zai4).

Comment: ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂也（副）／又（副）  **［相同］**  都是副词，作状语，都可以用于（既）。。。，也／又。。。＂的复句中，表示同一事物同时具有两个特点或性质，或两种情况同时存在，此时前后两个分句主语相同，可以互换：（１）周英和刘丽是小学同学，又是中学同学。（也✓）（２）我们班有韩国人，又有泰国人。（也✓）（３）林芳长得漂亮，又活泼开朗，大家都很喜欢她。（也✓）（４）他既会弹钢琴，也会拉小提琴，真是多才多艺。（又✓）（５）你既不想吃牛肉，也不想吃猪肉，到底要吃什么？（又✓）（６）王老师讲得很清楚，也很生动。（又✓）  **［不同］**    **１。**  ＂也＂可以表示两个不同的人或事物具有相同的情况，此时前后分句的主语不同；＂又＂没有这种用法：（１）张华是学物理的，我也是学物理的。（又✗）（２）树叶绿了，小草也绿了。（又✗）（３）报名表也填了，考试费也交了，在没别的事了。（又✗）（４）你也唱，我也唱，大家一起唱。（又✗）   **２。**  ＂又＂还可以表示同一动作行为或情况重复出现，或两个动作接连交替出现：（１）这部电影我以前看过，今天又看了一遍。（也✗）（２）时间过得真快，又到中秋节了！（也✗）（３）他拿着照片，看了又看，高兴得不得了。（也✗）（４）老人站起来又坐下去，坐下去又站起来。（也✗）（５）我做完教学作业以后，又开始听英语。（也✗）  **３。**  ＂又。

Comment: 。。又＂表示几种行为同时进行，或两种状态同时存在；
也。。。也。。。＂表示并列的行为、情况，不能互换：（１）老赵热情地招待客人，又倒茶，又递烟。（也✗）（２）这件衣服又宽又大，不合身。（也✗）（３）饭也吃了，酒也喝了，该走了。（又✗）（４）在这种场合，我吃也不是，不吃也不是。（又✗）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 也 and 又 can mean "also" . (也 is more literary, 又 is more colloquial)

> (既~也~) is a common structure that connect two verb or adjective phrases
>
> Example:
>
> "他既教油畫, **也**教中國畫" (beside teaching oil painting, he **also** teaches Chinese painting)

~

> (又~又~) and (既~又~) are common structures that connect two verb or adjective phrases
>
> Example:
>
> "他又教油畫, **又**教中國畫" (first 又 can be omitted )
>
> "既殺人**又**放火" - *beside killing people, he also burning down villages* (既 can be omitted )

However both 也 and 又 have other meanings that are not interchangeable. Most noticeably 又 can mean "again" , while 也 cannot; 也 can mean "still/ even" while 又 cannot.

> [也](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/333/)
>
> 1. **also**; besides; either; too
> 2. as well
> 3. still
> 4. even

~

> [又](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/750/)
>
> 1. and; **also**; again; in addition to
> 2. moreover; furthermore

Comment: btw would 也 and 都 be interchangeable for "also"? should this get posted as a separate question? thanks again for your help!

Comment: In certain context,  both 也 and 都 can mean "too". For example: "連他也被解雇了"/ 連他都被解雇了 (even he was fired too); Notice in both examples,   "even" is connected to "too" ( even~ too = 連~也/都). If the "even" meaning is removed, you can only say " 他也被解雇了" (He was also fired) , because 都 itself  already implied the meaning of "even"  . For example "他都被解雇了" means  "(even) he was fired too"

Comment: thanks! do you think i should post this as a separate question or are they largely interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

也 means "too", "also": 我也是. Me too.

又 means "again": 今天又下雨了. It rained again today.

In informal speech, 也 is more neutral. It simply conveys the information that something is the same as something else. 他也是一个学生。He is also a student.

又 can have a negative connotation. 他又这样! He is doing it again!